# Cufflinks module of plotly do not show z axis for scatter plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly

I am trying to do a scatter plot with a z axis using `cufflink` a wrapper library of `plotly` and `pandas`. I noticed the `z` argument of `iplot` but I cannot get it working.

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
init_notebook_mode()

import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()

df = cf.datagen.lines(3,columns=['a','b','c'])

df.iplot(x='a', y='b', z='c', kind='scatter', mode='markers')
```

But z axis is not displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out looking at the source code that the `z` argument is not taken into account with `kind=scatter` as kwarg.

I am jut sharing a solution that I found to serve my need using plotly. If someone manage to find a quicker solution with cufflinks I would be very pleased, otherwise this one will do the job. It also has the merits to display **time-scale** properly

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import iplot


def py_scatter_by_z(x, y, z=None, x_title=None, y_title=None, mode='markers', colorscale='Jet', showscale=True, size=10,
                    line_color='black',
                    line_width=1, date_format="%b'%y", n_ticks=8, opacity=.5, scatter_kwargs=dict(), **layout_kwargs):
    '''
    Plots a scatter plot between two variables x and y and colors each point according to a variable z.

    Plotly and genereralized version of plot_scatter_by_time.

    Args:
        x (1D-Series | list | 1-D Array): values of x-axis. 
        y (1D-Series | list | 1-D Array): values of y-axis.
        z (1D-Series | list | 1-D Array): values of z-axis used for colorscale. Could be Numeric or dates. 
        x_title (str): label of x_axis.
        y_title (str): label of y_axis.
        mode (str): Scatter mode, i.e. "markers" or "lines+markers". Default is markers 
        colorscale (str): Colorscale to use to color the points. 
                    See plotly colorscale/matplotlib colormap. 
                    Default is "Jet".
        showscale (bool): Show colorbar if True (default). 
        size (int): size of the markers. Default is 10. 
        line_color (str): color of edge line of markers. Default is "black".
        line_width (int): width of edge line of markers. Default is 1.
        date_format (str): format of the   
        n_ticks (int): Number of ticks to display in the colorbar.  
        opacity (float between 0 and 1): opacity/transparency of filled markers. Default is 0.5.
        scatter_kwargs (dict): dictionary passed as kwargs for scatter. Default is empty dictionary. 
        **layout_kwargs: kwargs of the function, used as layout kwargs.

    Returns: dictionary representing a plotly figure.

    '''

    # Basic trace
    trace = go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        mode=mode,
    )

    layout = go.Layout(xaxis=dict(title=x_title), yaxis=dict(title=y_title))
    layout.update(**layout_kwargs)

    # Coloring points
    if z is not None:
        z_all_dates = pd.Series(index=z).index.is_all_dates

        if z_all_dates:
            # Special treatment if z is a datetime vector
            color = pd.to_numeric(z)
            step = int(len(z) / n_ticks)
            z = list(z)
            ticktext = [date.strftime(date_format) for date in z[1::step]]
            tickvals = list(color)[1::step]
            colorbar = dict(nticks=n_ticks,
                            tickvals=tickvals,
                            ticktext=ticktext)
        else:
            color = z
            colorbar = dict()

        marker = {'marker': dict(size=size, color=color, colorscale=colorscale,
                                 showscale=showscale, opacity=opacity, colorbar=colorbar)}
        trace.update({'text': z})

    else:
        marker = {'marker': dict(size=size)}

    # Construct and plot figure
    marker['marker'].update({'line': {'color': line_color, 'width': line_width}})
    trace.update(marker)
    trace.update(**scatter_kwargs)
    data = [trace]
    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    iplot(fig)

    return fig


from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
init_notebook_mode()

import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()

df = cf.datagen.lines(3,columns=['a','b','c'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index) # Example with a time scale
py_scatter_by_z(df['a'], df['b'], df.index)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A scatter plot has only a x and y-axis. Setting `kind` to `scatter3d` adds the z-axis.

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
init_notebook_mode()

import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()

df = cf.datagen.lines(3,columns=['a','b','c'])

df.iplot(x='a', y='b', z='c', kind='scatter3d', mode='markers')
```

[image]

If you want to add a third dimension to your plot you can also use a scatter plot and add the information to your color. In this case it easier not to use cufflinks.

```
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()

df = cf.datagen.lines(3, columns=['a','b','c'])
trace1 = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(x=df.a, 
                                   y=df.b, 
                                   marker=dict(color=df.c,
                                               showscale=True), 
                                   mode='markers')
fig = plotly.graph_objs.Figure(data=[trace1])
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem is that 3d plots don't fit my needs. I detailed in my answer an example of what I expected by scatter with z scale. It's much more like an heatmap but without the ugly squares.

Comment: @MCMZL: See updated answer for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
# 1st create a data frame with 3 columns(I have taken a random data frame here)
train_data.head(5) #check the data frame
#plot the 3d scatter plot
train_data.iplot(kind = 'scatter3d',x='a',y='b',z='c')#here 'a','b' and 'c' 
are three columns of the data frame  
[3d scatter plot within two lines of code][1]
```